# JQuery cycle plugin + PNG overlay + Image alt text as title conflict

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, gallery

I am trying to achive the following:

- Create an image gallery using the JQuery Cycle plugin that shows images with titles (taken from the alt text)
- Each image has a PNG absolutley posiioned over the top to achieve rounded corners effect

Here's my gallery HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="pics">

<div class="photo-container" >
<img src="/path/to/image" alt="alt text as title" />
<img class="mask" src="path/to/mask" />
</div>

</div><!-- /slideshow -->

<div id="title"></div>
```

Here's my Jquery gallery function:

```
$(function() {

$('#slideshow').after('<div id="nav" class="nav"><span style="margin: 0 5px 0 30px;">next image</span>').cycle({
fx:     'fade',
timeout: 0,
cleartypeNoBg: true,
pager:  '#nav',
next:    '#slideshow',
before: onBefore
});
function onBefore() {
$('#title').html(this.alt);
}
$('#nav a').after('<span>&gt;</span>')   
});
</script>
```

Here is my CSS that handles the mask:

```
.photo-container {
  position: relative; 
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
  border: none;
} 

img.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  border: none;
}
```

The above does not output the alt text into the "title" div.  When I remove the mask, it works:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="pics">

<img src="/path/to/image" alt="alt text as title" />

</div><!-- /slideshow -->

<div id="title"></div>
```

Any ideas why the additonal div / image is casuing the title to not display?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your code,

```
$('#slideshow')
    .after('<div id="nav" class="nav"><span style="margin: 0 5px 0 30px;">next image</span>')
```

it looks like you missed a closing `/div` tag, so this does not look like it is generating a proper node/element. This is perhaps causing your problems? Compare to the following:

```
$('#slideshow')
    .after('<div id="nav" class="nav"><span style="margin: 0 5px 0 30px;">next image</span></div>')
```

Best of luck!
-Mike

Comment: Many thanks for your comment.  

Good spot, the <div> should be be closed, so at least that's picked up, unfortunatly it does not have an effect on outputting the "title" div.

Comment: could you try changing `this.alt` to `$(this).attr('alt')` ??

Comment: Thank you

That line amened to:
    $('#title').html($(this).attr('alt'));     

But still the same. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is equal to the `div`.  You need to get the `alt` attribute of the `img` within the `div`.

Change that line to:

```
$('#title').html($(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
```